# The Batch Update didn't update right away (Swift 3)

Tags: swift, core-data

I set a Batch Update that supposes to update the state of my UISwitch state. I put the code in UITableViewCell Class. In the console, it does return a message saying the result had been updated but when I go back and open the page again, the state still remains the same. However, when I rebuild the project, the state will be updated.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
class VerbTenseTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var TenseSwitch: UISwitch!

    @IBOutlet weak var TenseLabel: UILabel!
    var coreDataStack: CoreDataStack! = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).coreDataStack
    let batchUpdate = NSBatchUpdateRequest(entityName: "Setting")
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        TenseSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(BatchUpdatePresent(switchSate:)), for: .valueChanged)
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    func BatchUpdate(Batch: NSBatchUpdateRequest)
    {
        do {
            let batchResult = try coreDataStack.managedContext.execute(Batch) as! NSBatchUpdateResult
            print("Records updated \(batchResult.result!)")
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not update \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
    func BatchUpdatePresent(switchSate: UISwitch)
    {
        if(switchSate.isOn && TenseLabel.text == "Présent")
        { print(1)
            batchUpdate.propertiesToUpdate = [#keyPath(Setting.present) : true]
            batchUpdate.affectedStores = coreDataStack.managedContext.persistentStoreCoordinator?.persistentStores
            batchUpdate.resultType = .updatedObjectsCountResultType
        }
        else if (switchSate.isOn == false && TenseLabel.text == "Présent")
        {print(2)
            batchUpdate.propertiesToUpdate = [#keyPath(Setting.present) : false]
            batchUpdate.affectedStores = coreDataStack.managedContext.persistentStoreCoordinator?.persistentStores
            batchUpdate.resultType = .updatedObjectsCountResultType
        }
         else if (switchSate.isOn == true && TenseLabel.text == "Passé Composé")
        {print(3)
            batchUpdate.propertiesToUpdate = [#keyPath(Setting.passecompose) : true]
            batchUpdate.affectedStores = coreDataStack.managedContext.persistentStoreCoordinator?.persistentStores
            batchUpdate.resultType = .updatedObjectsCountResultType
            BatchUpdate(Batch: batchUpdate)
        }
        else if (switchSate.isOn == false && TenseLabel.text == "Passé Composé")
        {print(4)
            batchUpdate.propertiesToUpdate = [#keyPath(Setting.passecompose) : false]
            batchUpdate.affectedStores = coreDataStack.managedContext.persistentStoreCoordinator?.persistentStores
            batchUpdate.resultType = .updatedObjectsCountResultType
            BatchUpdate(Batch: batchUpdate)
        }

    }
```

and the following is the method that supposes to fetch the updated result and apply to the UISwitch

```
    func get()
{
    do {
         try coreDataStack.managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        Switch = try coreDataStack.managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        print(Switch.count)
        print(switchState.count)
        switchState.append(Switch[0].present)
        print("Switch Present is \(switchState[0]) and \(Switch[0].present)")
        switchState.append(Switch[0].passecompose)
        print("Switch Passe is \(switchState[1]) and \(Switch[0].passecompose)")

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

    }
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: When is `func get()` called?

Comment: Also, `func get()` does not appear to contain any code that attempts to update the state of a `UISwitch`-- so where does that update happen?

Comment: The get（）is in UITableViewController, I add the batch update method in UITableViewCell. So the program suppose to fetch the updated data in get（） after the data is updated in BatchUpdatePresent（）